# UITapGestureRecognizer not working when setting target programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add tap event listener on an `UIImageView` inside `UITableViewCell` so I added an `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it and used this code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.editTap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProfileTVC.editTapped(sender:))) 
        //editTap is an UITapGestureRecognizer
        ...
    }
}

func editTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapped")
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let tapIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) {
            if fields[tapIndexPath.row].field == "languages_spoken" {

            } else if fields[tapIndexPath.row].field == "password" {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I'm tapping on my `UIImageView` the `editTapped` is not being called. Also `UIImageView`'s user interaction is enabled

Comment: What is `editTap`? Where are you actually creating the `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: I've edited my post. `editTap` is an ``UITapGestureRecognizer @rmaddy

Comment: maybe there is a view overlaps editTap, use hierarchy debug to find it. @Amir_P

Comment: You only answered one of my two questions.

Comment: I've created it inside StoryBoard @rmaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add UITapGestureRecognizer with "addTarget"

Change addTarget method with this one in your CellForRowAt function;

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProfileTVC.editTapped(sender:)))
cell.editTap.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) //editTap should be the ImageView inside cell.
```

Comment: I've edited my post. `editTap` is an `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: Did you try my solution? I think you are adding in a wrong way.

Comment: yes it's working but my question is that why created gesture recognizer inside story board not working this way?

Comment: Do you have dynamic or static cells?

Comment: dynamic cells d

Comment: So app can't know which cells have gesture recognizer or which it should add gesture recognizer. I'm not sure If you add one gesture recognizer to a dynamic cell and work it for all...

Comment: The code in this answer isn't valid and won't compile since `cell.editTap` is a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 1):

You add target not gesture

```
  let tapPress = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProfileTVC. editTapped(_:)))
 cell.editTap.addGestureRecognizer(tapPress)
```

//

```
@objc func editTapped(_ gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer)
{ 


}
```

Comment: I've edited my post. `editTap` is an `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: it's name of function it may be anything